# Wordpress plugin compatibility explaination when wordpress releases its new version (theoretical)

Tags: wordpress, compatibility

Recently i updated my `wordpress` to its latest `version 3.4.1` and noticed that few of my plugins are only compatible upto 3.3 although they are working correctly for my site even with the latest version.

So does that means that i need to disable those plugins and look for the alternatives and these plugins are no more `SAFE` to use or it is something else( i downloaded all plugins from `wordpress.org` ONLY) .

Need a better clarification over this and let me know if some concept i m missing with the up gradation :) . Detailed answer is really appreciated and i will do my part then :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions. For this kind of issues you should try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As long as a plugin uses functions which are still working in the latest version of WordPress, all that needs to happen is what [Brian](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11345397/190829) explained -- the plugin author needs to go and update their plugin docs to show compatibility.

Comment: @JP: I don't think you need to update docs, just log in to wordpress.com as author and click on the "compatible with" on the right under the green forum button.

Comment: @BrianC I think you mean wordpress.org. That "Compatibility" section is only like a voting section, so people using the plugin can vote on whether it works. Authors need to update the documentation because you specify compatibility in the readme doc that is parsed by the WordPress SVN.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant wordpress.com! thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin authors need to explicitly remember to login and approve their plugin for use with a new release; I'm afraid it's not automatic.

The good news is that unless there's a huge change to the way something works, well developed plugins tend to stay compatible.

Bear in mind that downloading from wordpress.org in itself doesn't tell you that a plugin is 100% - it's all up to the authors, and some authors maintain their plugins well and others no longer look at them.

To assess whether a plugin is more likely to last the long term, look at how often it has been changed, and whether problems in the support forums have been responded to.  The number of stars tells you a little bit, and the number of downloads, if really high, tends to suggest that the plugin is well trusted.

Comment: yes that's true but i think they have a well set channel for plugin submission and security holes can't be filled at 100%, but i read somewhr that u can go with the wordpress.org plugin upto such an extent if they have not changed thr core API..thanks for the answer :)